# ProgressDialog never shows up when the task right after is an upload (or other processor intensitve process)

Tags: android

I'm trying to display a ProgressDialog to indicate that the user should wait while something uploads in the background, however, the device (galaxy tab) just freezes for the time that the upload happens and then when it comes out of its stupor it just goes to the next thing (having never displayed the ProgressDialog.

When I eliminate the upload, the dialog appears as expected. I'm guessing this is an async issue? The dialog simple never gets a time slice and by the time it does it's already been dismissed?

```
pd = ProgressDialog.show(getApplicationContext(),"", "Sending Image ...", true);
uploadImage(); //if I comment out this line, the dialog shows, otherwise not.
pd.dismiss();
```

Is there some way to block on the ProgressDialog line until it actually renders? Or am I overlooking something stupid (and obvious)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This is similar to what you are doing](http://www.androidsnippets.org/snippets/116/).

Long story short use a [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) and call `uploadImage()` inside `doInBackground()`

```
 new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute()
        {
             pd = ProgressDialog.show(getApplicationContext(),"", "Sending Image ...", true);
            Log.d(TAG, "onPreExecute()");
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params)
        {
            Log.d(TAG, "doInBackground() -- Here is the upload");
            uploadImages();
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void res)
        {
            Log.d(TAG, "onPostExecute()");
            pd.dismiss();
        }
    }.execute();
```

Comment: that doesn't work. The async task still appears to swallow up all the resources and the ProgressDialog doesn't show up until after the upload is finished.  What I really want is to be notified when the ProgressDialog has appeared on the screen and THEN to initiate the upload, but I can't figure out how to do that.

Comment: Are you sure you did exactly as above ?

Comment: I had missed the onPreExecute feature of this but before I saw your answer, I just wrote it as a thread and now it works (probably identical behind the scenes). I'm still confused by the param arrays, but now it's all working in my threaded version, so, I'm happy.  I'll give you the check mark cause I believe you that this solution is just as effective, though I'm not clear on what advantage this offers over a standard Thread class.

Comment: AsyncTask is just a convenience so that one does not have to worry about complicated threading. There is a limit to a number of AsyncTasks that can run at a single instant, so its not as powerful as threads. But is a hell of a lot of easier to use.